# Numerical Integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I have used the following code to evaluate an integral (val) numerically

```
mu = 0.0173262004;(*attenuation coefficient for E = ?*) 
k = (mu - 0.00324543007)/(0.00324543007); 
h = 150.; 
sz = 50.; 
eg = 0.7; 
qx = 1.0; 
u = 1.0; 
the = (22.5 Pi)/180; 
f1 = 1/(l^2 + z^2); 
f2 = 1 + k mu (l^2 + z^2)^0.5; 
f3 = Exp[-(z - h)^2/(2 sz sz)]; 
f4 = Exp[-(z + h)^2/(2 sz sz)]; 
f5 = Exp[-mu (l^2 + z^2)]; 
val = NIntegrate[
  2 Pi l f1 (f2 (f3 + f4) f5), {l, 0, Infinity}, {z, 0, Infinity}] 
dr[r_] := 0.0404 0.00324543007 eg qx val/((2 Pi)^0.5 u r sz the) 
LogPlot[dr[r], {r, 0, 10000}]
```

Now, i will be using the parameter (*sz*) as a function of *r*. For example, `sz=0.26*r^0.69;`
How to do this?
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you wish to define `sz` as a function of `r` instead of a constant (as it is now)?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Then define it as `sz[r_]:=0.26*r^0.69` and when calling it within something else, use `sz[r]`, replacing `r` with whatever variable is relevant (`r_` is a pattern so the input need not be explicitly the letter r).

Answer (score 1):

You can define your val now as a function of r, rather than as a constant. Then you will be able to operate with this function. I will show it within a short example, and you can then implement into your code by analogy. Consider an integral

```
sz=5;    
int=NIntegrate[x^2*Exp[-sz*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
    (*   0.0396333  *)
```

Now let us replace this sonstant sz by a function `sz = 0.25*r^0.69`:

```
int[r_] := NIntegrate[x^2*Exp[-0.25*r^0.69 x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}];
```

Now one can do with this function whatever he needs. Let us plot it, for example:

```
Plot[int[r], {r, 1, 5}, AxesLabel -> {r, int}]
```

giving this:

[image]
Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Corrected per input from Michael E2

```
mu = 0.0173262004;
(*attenuation coefficient for E=?*)
k = (mu - 0.00324543007)/(0.00324543007);
h = 150;
sz[r_] = 0.26*r^0.69;
eg = .7;
qx = 1.;
u = 1.;
the = (22.5 Pi)/180;
f1 = 1/(l^2 + z^2);
f2 = 1 + k mu (l^2 + z^2)^0.5;
f3[r_] = Exp[-(z - h)^2/(2 sz[r] sz[r])];
f4[r_] = Exp[-(z + h)^2/(2 sz[r] sz[r])];
f5 = Exp[-mu (l^2 + z^2)];

val[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[2 Pi l f1 (f2 (f3[r] + f4[r]) f5)],
  {l, 0, Infinity}, {z, 0, Infinity}]

dr[r_?NumericQ] :=
 0.0404*0.00324543007 eg qx val[r]/((2 Pi)^(1/2) u r sz[r] the) //
  Evaluate

logPlot = LogPlot[dr[r], {r, 200, 10000},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 51]
```

[image]

```
dr[200]
```

> 8.80707*10^-45

Comment: `dr[100]` gives errors for me.  Note that `LogPlot` effectively uses `Block[{r = 100},..]` etc.

Comment: The problem with `dr[100]` is that the parameter `r_?NumericQ` is localized and does not refer to the global variable `r` that appears in `sz` and its dependents.  `LogPlot` uses `Block` to set `r`, which sets the global `r`.  In `dr[100]`, the local function parameter `r` is `100`, but the global `r` remains an undefined variable.  The proper fix is to make `sz`, `f3`, and `f4` functions of `r`.  There are shorter workarounds, but they're kludgy (e.g., `dr[r0_?NumericQ] := Block[{r = r0}, <code>]` and `val := NIntegrate[...]`).